# Buefy: How to set icon-pack while registering components individually

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, buefy

In my Vue.js project's main.ts I was registering font-awesome icons as follows (as per the [Buefy documentation](https://buefy.org/documentation/icon)):

```
library.add(faArrowUp, faArrowLeft, faArrowRight, faExclamationCircle, faExclamationTriangle, faCalendar);
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

Vue.use(Vue, {
  defaultIconPack: 'fas',
  defaultIconComponent: 'font-awesome-icon'
});
```

This worked as intended and made the Buefy components make use of the relevant icons.

Now, to reduce my application's bundle size, I changed to registering only the components that are used by my app (as per the [documentation](https://buefy.org/documentation/start/)):

```
Vue.use(Loading);
Vue.use(Skeleton);
Vue.use(Table, {
  defaultIconPack: 'fas',
  defaultIconComponent: 'font-awesome-icon'
});
// more components...
```

I don't know now how to correctly register the icon pack. When I set the relevant properties to the options for the Table component as above, the component is not utilizing the icons.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I [found it](https://buefy.org/documentation/constructor-options):

```
Vue.use(Loading);
Vue.use(Skeleton);
Vue.use(Table);

ConfigProgrammatic.setOptions({
  defaultIconPack: 'fas',
  defaultIconComponent: 'font-awesome-icon'
});
```